# Git for Windows stopped working - VS Team Services

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am running VS 2017 on Windows Server 2012 and am trying to connect to Visual Studio Team Services. However, whenever I try to do a sync, fetch, etc Git for Windows crashes with the message "Git for Windows has stopped working".

This looks to be happening in git-remote-https.exe. I tried disabling my virus scanner but had no luck. I also installed the latest version of Git which didn't help.

Below are the details:

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: git-remote-https.exe
  Application Version:  2.11.1.0
  Application Timestamp:    00180000
  Fault Module Name:    r\Git\mingw32\bin\libssh2-1.dll!EVP_Cipher
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18696
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5915ecd6
  Exception Code:   c0000139
  Exception Offset: 0009d4c2
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 1abe
  Additional Information 2: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8
  Additional Information 3: 1abe
  Additional Information 4: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8
```

Comment: Did this happen only for a certain repo or all the git repo for VS? If all the repo have his problem, please check `libssh2-1.dll`. And It seems you installed 32bit git bash in `R:\Git`, what if you install 64bit git bash instead?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this *could* be due to a 'MinGit' install added by Visual Studio (see the Visual Studio Team reply to this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26539/vs2017-deployed-gitexe-not-usable.html)

I removed the VS Git install (for me at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\git.exe`).

Visual Studio then used my normal full install of git, and ran fine after that.